# Change the first two characters in PL SQL Query

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a PL SQL Query to show time and data types is string. The field is created from string values. Can I Replace the first two character in `SELECT` statement in some conditions?. For example, when the query result is `24:33:07 (HH:MM:SS)` the '`24`' is changed to '`00`', so it becomes `00:33:07`

Comment: `24:33:07` is not a valid 24 hour time.  How did you end up with this value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, that makes my app becomes error. that value was create from a report. I think there was a mistake when input in data source. So I want to change my query SELECT.

Comment: *"I have a PL SQL Query"* - Where's the query ? I don't see it.

Comment: Looks more like you want an _interval_ data type instead of _time_.

Comment: Would be better to enforce the validation on the input field itself, since said input is already illogical. Don't let front end mistakes affect you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `case when` and handle properly all cases, for instance like here:

```
with t(str) as (
  select '16:43:48' from dual union all
  select 'AA:17:01' from dual union all
  select '01:12:25' from dual union all
  select '24:33:07' from dual )
select str, case 
            when str like '24%' then '00'||substr(str, 3)
            when str like 'AA%' then '12'||substr(str, 3)
            else str
            end corrected
  from t
```

In my examples two rows were wrong and `24` was changed to `00` and `AA` to `12`.

Then you can verify if all times are ok using:

```
select to_date(corrected, 'hh24:mi:ss') from (...previous query...)
```

If something will be still wrong you get errors like ORA-01850, 01851, 01858. You can find incorrect values in PLSQL loop or using regular expressions.